# Preference not changing immediately in Android

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, preferences

In the `MainActivity.class`,

I am changing the value of a preference like so:

```
    mPrefs = StripedMain.this
                    .getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFS_NAME, 0);
            mPrefs.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
            onSharedPreferenceChanged(mPrefs, null);

public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences prefs,
                String key) {

                preVal = prefs.getString(key, "st");
if (preVal.equals("a")){
      prefs.edit().putString("name", "Rob").commit();
}
```

}

This works but the value on the screen itself does not change immediately but only after the settings screen has been closed and opened again.

So why is that and how do I fix it?

Comment: try to call those things which initially responsible to display those value

Comment: do not call `onSharedPreferenceChanged();` yourself. Just change the prefs from somewhere and it will be called for you. and in `onSharedPreferenceChanged();` method update your GUI like you might be doing in `onCreate()` to show the effect immediately.

Comment: tried both, not working.......

Comment: @Bhavin Nattar, please do not add your own tagline (_"Thanks in Advance..."_) to somebody else's post.  Usually, taglines are removed when editing, not added.  Thanks.  [Please see this posting on Meta for more information about taglines.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2950/157574)

Comment: @Romert, how is it going? I'm having the same issue here. Btw, are you talking about setting in Live Wallpaper?

Answer (score 0):

Hope you have defined an xml for your preferences. Assuming you are having an edittext pref, you should have something like this in pref xml:

```
<EditTextPreference
         android:summary="@string/summary" 
         android:title="@string/textinput" 
         android:key="input" 
         android:defaultValue= "@string/initialvalue" />
```

You need to define a default value, if you want to read this value and accordingly do some initialisation when your app starts and even before the user has not done any setting change. This default value will be used until the user stores a new value in this preference.

Your `MainActivity` should implement `OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener`

Use the below logic for reading and editing your sharedpref values

```
SharedPreferences mPrefs = getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFS_NAME, 0);
mPrefs.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
onSharedPreferenceChanged(mPrefs, input); // this will initialise with existing pref value

public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences prefs,
                String key) {

if (key.equals("input")) { // doing a check for key if you want to add more prefs in future
     preVal = prefs.getString(key, "st");
     if (preVal.equals("a")){
      prefs.edit().putString("name", "Rob").commit();
}
```